# Помощь в открытии и записи файла в структуре

Tags: c++, файлы, функции, структуры

Испытываю проблемы при записи и открытии файла. Делала вроде как в примере в методичке, но сохраняет ерунду. Библиотеки не предлагать, по заданию надо использовать данный способ :(  По идее должен сохраняться 2 файла (кек-бинарный) и (кек1-для юзера). Но в итоге в бинарном совсем как-то мало символов, а 2 пустой. 
И другой вопрос: чтобы в выводе заработала функция надо заново как-то создавать файл? Ибо он не видит и пишет как ошибка Ftab
Может я что-то упускаю
Спасибо заранее!

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>



struct ZAP
{
    int Number;
    char nazvanie[15];
    int vsego;
    int prom;
    int neprom;
    float dolneprom;
    float vypol;
};

void vvod(ZAP *u, int n);
void vyvod(ZAP *u, int n);

using namespace std;
int main() {


    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int Number, Itog3, Itog4, Itog5, i, otvet, prom, vsego, neprom, n;
    char nazvanie[15];
    float dolneprom, vypol, Itog6, Itog7;
    system("CLS");

    do {
        cout << "Введите кол-во ghtlghbznbq ( не более 30 ) -> ";
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (!(1 < n && n <= 30));
    ZAP *A = new ZAP[n];
    vvod(A, n);
    _getch();
    system("CLS");

    vyvod(A, n);


    _getch();


}

void vvod(ZAP *u, int n) {

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    float Itog1, Itog2, Itog3;
    FILE * Ftab, *f2;

    Ftab = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kek.txt", "wb");
    f2 = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kek1.txt", "w");
    if (Ftab == NULL)
    {
        perror("Ошибка при открытии файла A");
        _getch();
        exit(0);
    }

    int Number;
    char nazvanie[15];
    int vsego;
    int prom;
    int neprom;
    float dolneprom;
    float vypol;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Номер= \n", i);
        scanf("%d", &Number);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("Наименование п/п \n");
        gets_s(nazvanie);
        printf("Всего персонала по плану \n");
        scanf("%d", &vsego);
        printf("Промышленного персонала(фактически) \n");
        while (1) {
            scanf("%d", &prom);
            if (prom < vsego) {
                break;
            }
            else printf("No");
        }
        printf("Непромышленного(фактически) \n");
        while (1) {
            scanf("%d", &neprom);
            if ((prom + neprom) <= vsego) {
                break;
            }
            else printf("No");
        }

        u->Number = Number;
        strcpy(u->nazvanie, nazvanie);
        u->vsego = vsego;
        u->prom = prom;
        u->neprom = neprom;
        u->dolneprom = (neprom * 100) / vsego;
        u->vypol = ((prom + neprom) * 100) / vsego;
        cout << "Нажмите клавишу для продолжения\n";

        system("CLS");
        fwrite(&u, sizeof(u), 1, Ftab);
        u++;
    }
    F.close();
    fclose(Ftab);
    fclose(f2);
    _getch();

}


void vyvod(ZAP *u, int n) {
    int i;
    int Itog3, Itog4, Itog5;
    float  Itog6, Itog7;
    Ftab = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kek.txt", "rb");
    if (Ftab == NULL)
    {
        perror("Ошибка при открытии файла");
        getch();
        exit(0);
    }
    Itog3 = Itog4 = Itog5 = Itog6 = Itog7 = 0;
    printf(" Сведения о предприятиях \n");
    while (!feof(Ftab))

    {
        printf(" число %d название %15s всего %d промыш %d непромыш %d доля %5.2f выполнение %5.2f \n", u->Number,
            u->nazvanie, u->vsego, u->prom, u->neprom, u->dolneprom, u->vypol);

        Itog3 += u->vsego;
        Itog4 += u->prom;
        Itog5 += u->neprom;
        Itog6 += u->dolneprom;
        Itog7 += u->vypol;
        fread(&u, sizeof(u), 1, Ftab);
    }
    printf("===========================================\n");
    printf("Всего: персонала по плану: %d /n пром персонала: %d /n непромыш персон %d /n  доля непромыш %8.2f /n выполнение плана %8.2f \n",
        Itog3, Itog4, Itog5, Itog6, Itog7);
    _getch();
    fclose(Ftab);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте внимательно посмотрим на эту строку

```
fwrite(&u, sizeof(u), 1, Ftab);
```

здесь происходит "самая суть" - пишется структура в файл. Но сколько пишется?  `sizeof(u) * 1`. А это 4 или 8 байт (в зависимости от 32 или 64 бита бинарника). Более того, пишется в файл адрес указателя... Это как бы совсем не то. Скорее всего там должно быть так

```
fwrite(u, sizeof(ZAP), 1, Ftab);
```

О том, что в коде есть куча утечек, я умолчу. И не стоит смешивать `cout` и `printf`/`scanf`. И все таки определитесь, у Вас си или плюсы.

Comment: Это недоработанная программа, поэтому там все намешано в синтаксисе. На ZAP он все-таки ругается

Comment: проверил, на ZAP оно не ругается. Но ругается на 100500 других мест.

Comment: если убрать добавление файла в функции вывода, тк я так и не поняла как стоит подключать, то у меня в вижаке выдает только эту ошибку"error C2065: Zap: необъявленный идентификатор" Если менять только ту строчку, которую предложили

Comment: @Elvis, прошагайте ваш код в отладчике, всё станет понятней.

Comment: Я там поправил регистр. Нужно большими буквами

Comment: я создала это, там я забыла записать fread и еще что-то. Можете посмотреть по синтаксису правильно организовала функцию? Или упустила опять что-то. Ибо файл не хочет подключаться и работать там :(
void nizh(void)
{
FILE *Ftab;
ZAP B;
Ftab = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kek.txt", "rb");
 printf(" Натур В опт.цен\n");
 fread(&B, sizeof(B), 1, Ftab);
 double minp = B.vypol;
 while (!feof(Ftab))
 {
  if (B.vypol < minp)
  {
   minp = B.dolneprom;
   fread(&B, sizeof(B), 1, Ftab);
  }


 }cout << "н.гр " << minp << "%\n";

 fclose(Ftab); }

Comment: извиняюсь за нечитабельность в комментах

Comment: Да вроде нормально. Только вместо вывода через cout пишите уже так `printf("н.гр %f %%\n", minp);`.